# Calculate request rate for prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have a sample web app written in `python`.

Each container reports (using `prometheus-python` client library) its total requests.

Therefore, since I have 2 replicas, when querying in prometheus dashboard for `my_metric_request` I get 2 time series (one for each pod)

```
myapp_requests_overall_total{container="myapp", endpoint="metricsport", instance="172.17.0.4:8282", job="my-service-exposing-the-metrics", namespace="default", pod="my-app-ff75c4784-xxtx4", service="my-service-exposing-the-metrics"}
243
myapp_requests_overall_total{container="myapp", endpoint="metricsport", instance="172.17.0.4:8282", job="my-service-exposing-the-metrics", namespace="default", pod="my-app-ff75c4784-dk40", service="my-service-exposing-the-metrics"}
```

My question is how can I produce (having the request sum) a metric that will indicate the rate of the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the result by one (or more) *usefull* label.
For example, if you want to monitor the average number of request by job, then you'll have the following :

```
sum(rate(myapp_requests_overall_total[5m])) by (job)
```

Comment: Thank you; what does the `5m` in the brackets imply?

Comment: It means that the rate is done on a 5 minutes period. It'll average the result based on all the samples during that period